# How do Javascript libraries works on a client computer

Tags: javascript

I have searched a lot in the Internet about Javascript libraries. But I still have a question: 
How do Javascript libraries works on a client computer? 
Is it works like jQuery, where Client download a script file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they are downloaded by the client and executed by the browser's JavaScript runtime. JavaScript is downloaded via HTTP, the same protocol used for downloading HTML, CSS, images etc...

jQuery is just a regular JavaScript library. Nothing special. Popular - but by no means special!

Answer (score 0):

Java script libraries such JQuery
should add to page by  tag
so when a browser request a page with  tag that referenced to Jquery library file
the web server process the request and post the page include JQuery library